# Second Do While statement not firing up

Tags: vba, ms-word

The second Do While Statement not getting executing. The first step is to find the character "<<" and then extend the selection to ">>" and then highlight in yellow. The code blocks works when executed separately.

```
Sub AcceptChanges()

Dim WordContentt As Word.Range
Dim sFindText As String
Dim LastDigits As String

Set WordContentt = ActiveDocument.Content

sFindText = "<<"

With WordContentt.Find

  Do While .Execute(Findtext:=sFindText)

            LastDigits = Right(WordContentt.Sentences(1), 2)
            If InStr(LastDigits, ".") > 0 Then

            WordContentt.Sentences(1).Select
            Word.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-2, Extend:=wdExtend
            Word.Selection.Range.Revisions.RejectAll

             Else

                WordContentt.Sentences(1).Select
                Word.Selection.Range.Revisions.RejectAll

             End If

        Loop
 End With

Word.Selection.HomeKey

With WordContentt.Find

Do While .Execute(Findtext:=sFindText)
    Word.Selection.Select
    Word.Selection.MoveEndUntil Cset:=">>"
    Word.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Word.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 7

    Loop

End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

I have included comments to explain the actions.

```
Sub AcceptChanges()

    Dim WordContentt As Word.Range
    Dim sFindText As String
    Dim LastDigits As String

    Dim startText As String
    Dim endText As String

    Set WordContentt = ActiveDocument.Content

    sFindText = "<<"

    With WordContentt.Find

        Do While .Execute(Findtext:=sFindText)

            LastDigits = Right(WordContentt.Sentences(1), 2)

            If InStr(LastDigits, ".") > 0 Then

                WordContentt.Sentences(1).Select
                Word.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-2, Extend:=wdExtend
                Word.Selection.Range.Revisions.RejectAll

            Else

                WordContentt.Sentences(1).Select
                Word.Selection.Range.Revisions.RejectAll

            End If

        Loop
    End With

    ' To begin searching the whole document again
    Set WordContentt = ActiveDocument.Content

    ' You have to escape the characters with "\" otherwise they are invalid
    startText = "\<\<"
    endText = "\>\>"

    ' Clear formatting to be sure there's nothing saved in the settings before
    WordContentt.Find.ClearFormatting
    WordContentt.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With WordContentt.Find
        ' This will look for text contained between start and end text
        .Text = startText & "*" & endText
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        WordContentt.Find.Execute

        ' Loop to find in the whole document
        While WordContentt.Find.Found
            WordContentt.HighlightColorIndex = 7
            WordContentt.Find.Execute
        Wend

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

May Try the modified code

```
Sub AcceptChanges()
Dim WordContentt As Word.Range
Dim sFindText As String
Dim LastDigits As String

Set WordContentt = ActiveDocument.Content
sFindText = "<<"
With WordContentt.Find

    Do While .Execute(Findtext:=sFindText)
      LastDigits = Right(WordContentt.Sentences(1), 2)
        If InStr(LastDigits, ".") > 0 Then
        WordContentt.Sentences(1).Select
        Word.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-2, Extend:=wdExtend
        Word.Selection.Range.Revisions.RejectAll
        Else
        WordContentt.Sentences(1).Select
        Word.Selection.Range.Revisions.RejectAll
        End If
    Loop
End With

Word.Selection.HomeKey
Set WordContentt = ActiveDocument.Content ' added after find range WordContentt used to be redefinerd

With WordContentt.Find

Do While .Execute(Findtext:=sFindText)
    WordContentt.Select                      ' modified
    Word.Selection.MoveEndUntil Cset:=">>"
    Word.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Word.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 7
Loop

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you so much. Could you please mind giving the reason for your edit. I had already set the value of WordContentt. Why you are setting it again.

Comment: the range used with find gets redefined, we have to set it to document content again. May refer [link[( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find)